# Position of ContextMenu vs ContextMenuStrip

Tags: c#, .net, position, contextmenu, contextmenustrip

I am trying to add the first ContextMenuStrip to an application, as a menu.  However only ContextMenu's appear within the bounds of the application window, ContextMenuStrips appear outside of the application window.

This application I have started maintaining is a kind of dock or toolbar that works similar to the Windows taskbar;  it consumes an edge of the screen and other windows can not appear, or maximize, over it.  This application currently runs across the top of the screen and the ContextMenuStrips appear at the correct co-ordinates horizontally, but in vertical terms incorrectly appears at the bottom of the application window.

(I am new to maintaining this app, so I'm not sure how it controls how other windows can't appear, or maximize, over it in the same manner as the taskbar.)

Edit with image for clarification;
The purple line is the bounds of the monitor, the light blue box is the bounds of the app that behaves like the Windows taskbar, the dark blue box is the bounds of the button we want to click to make the menu appear, the green box is the bounds of the ContextMenu for that button (as expected), and the problem is the orange box being the bounds of the ContextMenuStrip (it is appearing below where it should).  I would like the orange box to appear in the same position as the green box.

[image]

Comment: What is the question here exactly, what positions to expect from a ContextMenuStrip vs a ContextMenu?

Answer (score 0):

How is the `ContextMenuStrip` created and how is it shown?

This example uses a dynamically created `ContextMenuStrip` and it works for me:

```
ContextMenuStrip cms = new ContextMenuStrip();

private void button4_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        cms.Items.Add("Test Menu");
        cms.Show(button4.PointToScreen(e.Location));
    }
}
```

The dynamic creation should however be irrelevant.

But maybe the docking you mention is interfering? How is it implemented?

Comment: thanks for the demo, I had something similar myself to break the issue down to my diagram above.  "How is it implemented?" is a great question and something I sense I need to figure out before anyone could further